# Moving point shapefile to the centroid of polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, arcgis-10.1, centroids

I have this point shapefiles on top of a bounded polygon. I would like to move each point to the centroid of each bounded polygon.

Is there an automatic way in ArcGIS 10.1 of solving this?

Like in the image shown below

[image]

Answer (score 5):

if you don't have an advanced licence, here is how you can do :

add 2 fields on your polygons, one for X and the other for Y

use the "calculate geometry field" to extract the X and Y coordinates of your polygon

use the spatial join tool to transfer the attributes of the polygons to the points

with the X and Y coordinate from table of this new set of points, [make a table view](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006v000000) for this data then create an [XY layer event](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006z000000). This will give you new points with all the attributes of your initial point feature class and located at the position of the centroid.

Comment: How can I create an XY layer event?

Comment: there is a tool called "Make XY Layer event" (I've added a link in my answer), or you can go in the menu File > add data > add XY data. I forgot to mention that the point feature class will not be visible in you dropdown of feature layers, so you first need to create a table view for your feature class (or copy its attribute table to a new table, but table view is better imho)

Answer (score 3):

If you have an Advanced level license of ArcGIS for Desktop you can use the [Feature To Point (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003m000000) tool:

> Creates a feature class containing points generated from the
>   representative locations of input features.

... probably with its INSIDE option ...

> Specifies whether to use representative centers of input features or
>   locations contained by input features as the output point locations.
>
> •CENTROID —Uses the representative center of an input feature as its
>   output point location. This is the default. This point location may
>   not always be contained by the input feature.
>    •INSIDE —Uses a location
>   contained by an input feature as its output point location.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use field calculator.

For centroid X:

```
!shape.centroid!.x
```

and for Y:

```
!shape.centroid!.y
```

Next from menu `File -> Add Data -> Add XY Data` - create new centroids layer. Last step is just making few Spatial Joins to retrieve attributes of original points.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a standard or an advanced license in arcgis, you probably have a fast procedure instead using the calculate geometry for coordinates and spatial join to copy them to your points. In Editor Toolbox you can use the Snap tool that will do the snap of your points to the centroid of the polygon.

1 - feature to point and for the output you can create a in_memory\centroid_temp

2 - use the Snap tool in the toolbox and do the snap from your points to the centroid_temp

Answer (score 0):

first convert the area to the point, so we have determined the central point of the area data. Then type snap in the search section and select the top tool, then specify that you want to snap to the central point and here is your result point snapped to the central point.